# Reduce the execution time of for loops in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am stuck with for loops execution in `pandas`.

Below is the code snippet,

```
for ix, pt in result.iterrows():
    for index,row in frame_SuggestedDose.iterrows():
        isTrue = False
        if (pt[0]==row[0] and pt[4]==row[10]):
            # print("found")
            pt[8] = row[2]
            isTrue = True
        if(isTrue or pt[4]>datetime.now().date()):
            break
        result.loc[ix] = pt
```

In above code, 0,10,2,4 are the index of columns in data frames.

I want to copy `value` from frame_SuggestedDose to result if result patient id is same as frame_SuggestedDose patient id and dates are same

Head of result frame:

```
patientId   Date    IntervalDate    IntervalName    start_dt    Dose    FastingBloodGlucose IntervalSuggestedReason IntervalStatus  BGL SuggestedDose
006b5d  2017-09-08 20:30:00 2017-09-08 20:30:00 Int1    2017-09-08  NaN NaN suggested_dose_reason_new_care_plan NaN NaN 14.0
```

for frame_SuggestedDose frame

```
    patientId   category    value   units   effective   status  fasting hypo    suggestedDose   suggestedReason effective_dt    effective_tm    dailyDoseTime   dose_dt dose_tm
   006b5d51 DOSE_SUGGESTION 14.0    units   2017-09-08 20:30:00 active  0.0 0.0 0.0 suggested_dose_reason_new_care_plan 2017-09-08  20:30:00    1970-01-01 20:30:00 1970-01-01  20:30:00
```

It is taking around 2 hours to execute.

How can the execution time be reduced?

I am using Jupyter Notebook

Comment: In pandas, you almost never have to use loop. Please post head of your df and the question, you might get a better solution

Comment: @Vaishali Please edited post!

Comment: Could you be more specific as what you're trying to achieve with your code snippet? As @Vaishali suggested, post a toy problem with a sample dataframe clearly explaining what it is that you're trying to achieve. Without the context of your problem it's almost impossible to suggest how you can improve your code.

Comment: @doktakay post edited.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code

```
result = result.drop("value",axis=1)
result = pd.merge(result,
                  frame_SuggestedDose[["patientId","effective_dt","value"]],
                  left_on=["patientId","Date"],
                  right_on=["patientId","effective_dt"],
                  how="left")
```